# Sql Sync over internet

Tags: sql, linked-server, database-replication

What is the best solution to sync tables between Servers over the internet?

Situation is that there is one SQL- Server lets say "Main", and a lot of SQL-Servers "Crowd", which all got the same Database with identical Tables for loacal work.

So i want to sync a few tables of the "Crowd" to the "Main" only one way Crowd -> Main

- Option 1: linked server with triggers (bad solution... )
- Option 2: Replication which isn´t that easy cause the Crowd is all local

what is the best solution to do that?

Comment: try to post your question [here](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: ok. thx for post http://superuser.com/questions/600740/sql-sync-over-internet